# ¿Como puedo leer o imprimir un bloque de lineas o datos de un archivo, entre dos lineas o dos palabras claves dentro del el archivo en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo varios archivos con el mismo formato y deseo leer un bloque de esos archivos  desde la línea donde aparecen los números o los datos del tiempo, voltaje y corriente, hasta la línea 'final de los datos', este sería un ejemplo o algo parecido a los archivos

Archivo:

```
Hay chicas chachareras que chacotean con chicos chazos. Y un chico mete al
chillón de la chepa un chichón por chirrichote, y el chiste, y lo 
chocante, es que la chepa se le ha chafado con la hinchazón del chirlo.

Datos del archivo número de variables  4: 

     Tiempo, Voltaje, Corriente
     0.0, 110.0, 6.92820323028
     0.000333333333333, 109.132617145, 6.37223934419
     0.000666666666667, 106.544147724, 5.71578143706
     0.001, 102.275413448, 4.96918224223
     0.00133333333333, 96.3937348048, 4.14421607499
     0.00166666666667, 88.9918693812, 3.25389314461
     0.002, 80.1865490164, 2.31225437556
     0.00233333333333, 70.1166388724, 1.33414997373
     0.00266666666667, 58.9409474477, 0.335005229834
Final de los datos importantes 

Treinta y tres tramos de troncos trozaron tres tristes trocadores de troncos
y triplicaron su trabajo, triplicando su trabajo de trozar troncos y troncos.

Final del archivo.
```

Y quiero que me imprima algo más o menos así:

```
['Tiempo,', 'Voltaje,', 'Corriente', '0.0,', '110.0,', '6.92820323028,',
 '0.000333333333333,', '109.132617145,', '6.37223934419,', 
 '0.000666666666667,', '106.544147724,', '5.71578143706,', '0.001,', 
 '102.275413448,', '4.96918224223,0.00133333333333,', '96.3937348048,', 
 '4.14421607499', '0.00166666666667,', '88.9918693812,', '3.25389314461,', 
 '0.002,', '80.1865490164,', '2.31225437556,', '0.00233333333333,', 
 '70.1166388724,', '1.33414997373,', '0.00266666666667,', '58.9409474477,', 
 '0.335005229834']
```

O que me lea solo los datos y me omita las líneas que hay antes  y las que hay después  de estos, algo  así:

```
  0.0, 110.0, 6.92820323028
  0.000333333333333, 109.132617145, 6.37223934419
  0.000666666666667, 106.544147724, 5.71578143706
  0.001, 102.275413448, 4.96918224223
  0.00133333333333, 96.3937348048, 4.14421607499
  0.00166666666667, 88.9918693812, 3.25389314461
  0.002, 80.1865490164, 2.31225437556
  0.00233333333333, 70.1166388724, 1.33414997373
 0.00266666666667, 58.9409474477, 0.335005229834
```

Son varios archivos y todos empiezan de la misma forma aparece la línea 'Datos del archivo número de variables'  y los datos termina antes de la línea 'Final de los datos importantes'  ya lo había intentado hacer con readline() pero no me da el resultado

Comment: El número de línea donde empiezan los datos que quieres extraer es el mismo para todos los archivos o varía según el archivo? La cantidad de observaciones es igual para todos los archivos o varia según el archivo? (en tu ejemplo son 9 observaciones)

Comment: no es el mismo numero de lineas para los lo otros archivos, unos traen mas lineas y otros menos lineas.

Comment: no es la misma posición de la linea y la cantidad de observaciones varia en cada archivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a suponer que las cadenas de inicio y final las tenemos en las variables `inicio` y `final`, respectivamente. Se podría hacer de esta manera:

```
inicio = "Datos del archivo"
final = "Final de los datos"

resultado = []

with open("Archivo.txt") as fichero:

    # descartar las primeras líneas
    fpos = (linea for linea in fichero
               if not line.startswith(inicio))

    # recoger las líneas hasta la siguiente marca
    for linea in fpos:
        if linea.startswith(final):
            break
        resultado += linea
```

De una manera algo más elegante y funcional:

```
from itertools import takewhile

inicio = "Datos del archivo"
final = "Final de los datos"

with open("Archivo.txt") as fichero:

    # descartar las primeras líneas
    fpos = (linea for linea in fichero
               if not line.startswith(inicio))

    # recoger las líneas hasta la siguiente marca
    resultado = list(takewhile(lambda s: not s.startswith(final), fpos))
```

Comment: ¡+1 por la manera funcional! :)